# WPF animation only moves in one direction

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation

I have a series of triggers for controlling a bar that is supposed to move up and down. Each time it is given one of these randomly selected values, it slides into the appropriate position:

```
<Trigger Property="Content" Value="B000">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="B000" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Content" Value="B125">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="B125" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".125" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".125" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Content" Value="B250">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="B250" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".25" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".25" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Content" Value="B500">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="B500" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".5" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".5" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Content" Value="B750">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="B750" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".75" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To=".75" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Content" Value="B1k0">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="B1k0" HandoffBehavior="SnapshotAndReplace">
            <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bar2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```

But for some reason, it only ever moves up. The parts where it's supposed to move down again, it just sits there. Stopping the animation between changes only causes it to begin again from the bottom, and that's not what I want.

Comment: You can try *not specifying* `HandoffBehavior` and `FillBehavior` for all of your animations.

Comment: That was how they were before I added those two. And they've been in every combination, too.

Comment: Try assigning the triggers from the top down.  If the problem it is will not go down or it will not fire a trigger a second time.

Comment: ok... that made it go up only for the first one, then it would only move down. Same kind of behaviour - the parts where it moves up again are just sitting there.

Comment: What type of control is bar1?

Comment: it's a `GradientStop` inside an `OpacityMask`. One is black and the other is transparent, and they move up and down with each other so the image just ends where the value is. There are other controls in there, but I truncated them for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I suspect the storyboard is doing what you expect but the control is not.  I would test the same storyboard but on another property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42420/discussion-between-patrick-and-blam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with going down lol but every animation/trigger has EnterAction and ExitAction.

To me it sounds like you are seeking for ExitAction which will allow you to move that thingy back to its start position. :)

Take a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.exitactions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here is an example :

```
<Style x:Key="PropertyTriggerExampleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

      <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
              To="1" Duration="0:0:1" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.EnterActions>
      <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
              To="0.25" Duration="0:0:1" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.ExitActions>          
    </Trigger>               
  </Style.Triggers>    
</Style>
```

**Edit:**

Then you need to have multiple DoubleAnimations like this:

```
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation .... />
            <DoubleAnimation ... />
            <DoubleAnimation ... />
            <DoubleAnimation ... />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
```

Comment: No, it's not supposed to move back to its start position. The next trigger is supposed to move it to a new position (higher or lower) from where the previous one ended.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. You do not need triggers you need just animations. They will be executed one after another.

Comment: Oh hey, turns out I can put nest the storyboards themselves. I can randomly generate sequences from StaticResource and set them off instead.